# How to suppress the "Authentication Required" Popup from browser?

Tags: angularjs

[image]For the invalid credentials i am getting an "Authentication Required" Popup. How to suppress this popup and let my application handle this 401 error case?

Comment: I don't there is problem with Angular here. This is a server configuration issue. The service is returning a challenge response, which the browser is intercepting and showing login popup. Depending upon server configuration you need to disable basic\ntml\kerberos authentication.

Comment: What is your server platform?

Comment: The only way to not get the login dialog from the browser is to not send back a 401 from the server.

Comment: @ Chandermani Apache web server

Answer (score 0):

if you're using PHP.

depending on how your back end is set,
check if you have:

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
```

this is how it should be:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized', true, 401);
```

see PHP header() [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Comment: Hi Nitsan, Thanks for the reply. I am using JQuery to contact apache web server.

Comment: @krishnakumar this appears to be a back-end issue, you'll need to change server response.